# Github page is either showing blank page or the read me file

Tags: reactjs, templates, github, single-page-application, github-pages

I am using a **react** protfolio template, and **the single page app**, loads perfect when I host it locally. But when I try to host on github pages, it shows me the read me file (I guess because no copy of the index.html file in the root), but even then I make a copy of the html file in the root, it just shows me a blank page.

Why the big difference between what I see localy and how it is displayed on github pages? How do I fix this?

Here is the code:
https://github.com/davidlindercodes/Ultimate-React-Portfolio

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is because, you didn't build your `React` app or create `gh-pages` branch.

**What you have to do**

You have to build your `React` app and move the files in `dist` folder to a branch called `gh-pages`. Then Github Pages will render the `index.html` in the `gh-pages` branch.

Refer [How to deploy React App to GitHub Pages](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f)

Comment: thank you! Actually, I think I do not have a dist folder? If I build my react app usiung npm run build, or yarn run build, it gives me a 'build' folder, if this what you a refering to? Should I rename this gh-pages?

Comment: You have to create an empty branch `gh-pages` and push the contents of `build` folder into the `gh-pages` branch.